# Is there a tracker of how many Sabu Statues I've Smashed, outside of finding a new one and smashing it?

Tags: river-city-girls

I know there's lists on the internet of where each Statue is, but outside of the number that pops up after smashing a statue, is there a way to know how many undamaged ones are out there? I only know I'm at 22/25 due to finding another one.